# Lucene foreign chars problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

I'm having some serious issues using Zend_Lucene and foreign characters like åäö. These issues appear both when the index is created and when it's queried. I've tried both iso-8859-1 and utf-8.

### ISO-8859-1

The query that doesn't work looks like "`+_area:skåne`". With Zend_Lucene I'm getting no matches, but if I run this query in Luke I get many matching docuements.

The index contains 20 fields. The "_area" field is added with the following syntax:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('_area', strtolower($item['area']), 'iso-8859-1'));
```

I am using the `Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive` analyzer.

While running indexing, the error message below appeared sometimes (the documents indexed were randomly selected from DB with iso-8859-1 encoding)

> Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in TextNum.php.

This was "solved" by checking if $this->_input is empty, as it seemed that this caused the notices. Note: The weird query results were a pre-existing condition.

When I search keyword fields using foreign characters I receive the error above, but when I search text fields it behaves differently. Then it generates about a hundred of the error below.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1996 in \Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm.php on line 472

But it produces what looks like a correct result set! On a side note, this second query doesn't generate any results in Luke.

### UTF-8

I've also tried UTF-8 because, to my knowledge, Zend_Lucene uses it internally. Since the data set is ISO-8859-1, I convert it using `utf8_encode`. But the indexing produces the following errors.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 266979 in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentInfo.php
>   on line 632
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentMerger.php
>   on line 196
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentMerger.php
>   on line 200
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentWriter.php
>   on line 231
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentWriter.php
>   on line 231
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 250595 in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentInfo.php
>   on line 2020
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentInfo.php
>   on line 2020
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
>   \Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\SegmentWriter.php
>   on line 465
>   ...

---

So. Can someone please shed some light? :) I believe (after days of googling) that I'm not the only one experiencing this.

Comment: please post your solution. We need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try using a [UTF-8 compatible text analyzer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.charset.html#zend.search.lucene.charset.utf_analyzer).
It looks like the analyzer you are using destroys the non-ASCII characters.
You should make sure that the text is input properly, and that it reaches Lucene in the proper format.

Comment: I actually was able to solve this right after I posted, but your answer would probably have lead me to the solution.

I went the UTF-8 way, and using all mb_* functions and such, I managed to run the indexing without errors. It seems to be working now, and I can query the index and it returns valid results.

Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Znarkus please post your solution. We need it.

Comment: @runrunforest This was a long time ago, so I'm not entirely sure what did the trick. But I think I made sure everything was encoded in UTF-8. But we've dropped Zend_Lucene in favour of Solr since then, because Zend_Lucene doesn't scale at all; it's very slow. Good luck!